# Closing process start from windows application on application close or exit

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on windows application. i have to run some window exe from my app, i am able to do the same but when i close my application these exe remains on running condition, i am not getting how can i close those exe. Please suggest some tips.

To run the Process

```
 private void StartChildProcess(string fileName)
    {
        Process newProcess = new Process();
        newProcess.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(fileName); ;
        newProcess.Start();
        localProcess.Push(newProcess);
    }
```

To close the process

```
 private void CloseStartedProcesses()
    {
        while (localProcess.Count > 0)
        {
            Process process = localProcess.Pop();
            if (process != null && !process.HasExited)
            {
                process.CloseMainWindow();
                process.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: How do you close that application? Show some code!

Comment: i tried to store the process info on the processinfo type variable and then trying to somevariable.kill() but no luck its generating the error "Cannot process request because the process has exited."

Comment: If the process has exited, then that means it's already closed. Problem solved. Update your question with sample code and more information if the problem *isn't* solved.

Comment: are you able to hit breakpoint at process.close()? If yes does it contain proper value?

Comment: when control goes to process.close() its generate the error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Process[] p = Process.GetProcessesByName("osk");
foreach (var item in p)
{
    item.Kill();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Some options:

- Setup some communication system so the Main application can alert the other application to shutdown (read up on some WCF information or remoting)
- Create a do.shutdown file and let the second application check if that file exists, simple but efficient.
- Use the process.Kill options
- Use Sendkey or equivalent to send a 'quit' key combination

Comment: This is not wcf application this is simple winform application.

Comment: Wcf is just a library you can add to the winform application, too bad you'll have to change the target application to recieve the Wcf messages to shutdown. I guess the Sendkey or equivalent would be the 'best' option.

Comment: Thanks Dude, but i am totally new in windows application development, i am a web developer thats why i am facing these problems. i don't have idea about wcf.

Answer (score 1):

Use Windows API - P/Invoke. `FindWindow()` or `EnumWindows()` to get the window handle. Then you can send `WM_CLOSE` or `WM_QUIT` to end the application via the `SendMessage()` function.

Note that if the application checks for user input on exiting (like a MessageBox asking weather the user really wants to quit) the only option might be to send `WM_DESTROY` which would be equivalent to `Process.Kill` (at least in respects to causing data loss - I am not certain it is the absolute equivalent).

Answer (score 0):

The reason that the EXE you've ran from your application doesn't terminate once you close your application is probably because the 2nd application runs as a DIFFERENT, SEPARATE process.

If you run another process with `System.Diagnostics.Process`, it will remain in background until terminated manually or until it finishes it's job.

Comment: is there any way to close the same .

Answer (score 0):

try this Process proc = Process.GetProcessesByName("processname");
      proc.Kill();

Comment: `Kill` terminates the process forcibly, which is very likely not what you want. `CloseMainWindow` would be a better choice.

Comment: Actually i am try to running osk.exe from my app, and i try to close it but i am unable. is there any way to do the same.

Comment: how are you trying to close it?